# How to evalute a string twice in Powershell

Tags: string, variables, powershell, eval

anyone know how to evalute a string twice in powershell?

from example 
$l1 = yes
$l2 = no

for (i=0;i -lt 2; i++)
{
echo $1$i
}

Comment: What should be the output from that code? There are some syntax errors..

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly then this code may do the job:

```
$l1 = 'yes'
$l2 = 'no'

# make and evaluate the expression:
for ($i = 1; $i -le 2; $i++) {
    Invoke-Expression "`$l$i"
}

# or, to be embedded into a string:
for ($i = 1; $i -le 2; $i++) {
    @"
Value is: $(Invoke-Expression "`$l$i")
"@
}
```

Comment: Invoke-Expression "`$l$i" was exactly what i was looking for! thanks

Comment: Note that you can also get the value with `(Get-Variable "l$i").Value`, without having to invoke an arbitrary expression.